# Is converting mysql to mysqli extremely necessary?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, acl

Here's my deal:
I found a simple ACL, and have absolutely fallen in love with it. The problem? It's all in mysql, not mysqli. The rest of my site is written in mysqli, so this bothers me a ton.

My problem is that the ACL can easily connect without global variables because I already connected to the database, and mysql isn't object oriented.

1) Is it needed to convert to mysqli?
2) How can I easily convert it all?

Code:

```
<?

    class ACL
    {
        var $perms = array();       //Array : Stores the permissions for the user
        var $userID = 0;            //Integer : Stores the ID of the current user
        var $userRoles = array();   //Array : Stores the roles of the current user

        function __constructor($userID = '')
        {
            if ($userID != '')
            {
                $this->userID = floatval($userID);
            } else {
                $this->userID = floatval($_SESSION['userID']);
            }
            $this->userRoles = $this->getUserRoles('ids');
            $this->buildACL();

        }

        function ACL($userID = '')
        {
            $this->__constructor($userID);
            //crutch for PHP4 setups
        }

        function buildACL()
        {
            //first, get the rules for the user's role
            if (count($this->userRoles) > 0)
            {
                $this->perms = array_merge($this->perms,$this->getRolePerms($this->userRoles));
            }
            //then, get the individual user permissions
            $this->perms = array_merge($this->perms,$this->getUserPerms($this->userID));
        }

        function getPermKeyFromID($permID)
        {
            $strSQL = "SELECT `permKey` FROM `permissions` WHERE `ID` = " . floatval($permID) . " LIMIT 1";
            $data = mysql_query($strSQL);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($data);
            return $row[0];
        }

        function getPermNameFromID($permID)
        {
            $strSQL = "SELECT `permName` FROM `permissions` WHERE `ID` = " . floatval($permID) . " LIMIT 1";
            $data = mysql_query($strSQL);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($data);
            return $row[0];
        }

        function getRoleNameFromID($roleID)
        {
            $strSQL = "SELECT `roleName` FROM `roles` WHERE `ID` = " . floatval($roleID) . " LIMIT 1";
            $data = mysql_query($strSQL);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($data);
            return $row[0];
        }

        function getUserRoles()
        {
            $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `user_roles` WHERE `userID` = " . floatval($this->userID) . " ORDER BY `addDate` ASC";
            $data = mysql_query($strSQL);
            $resp = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
            {
                $resp[] = $row['roleID'];
            }
            return $resp;
        }

        function getAllRoles($format='ids')
        {
            $format = strtolower($format);
            $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `roles` ORDER BY `roleName` ASC";
            $data = mysql_query($strSQL);
            $resp = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
            {
                if ($format == 'full')
                {
                    $resp[] = array("ID" => $row['ID'],"Name" => $row['roleName']);
                } else {
                    $resp[] = $row['ID'];
                }
            }
            return $resp;
        }

        function getAllPerms($format='ids')
        {
            $format = strtolower($format);
            $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `permissions` ORDER BY `permName` ASC";
            $data = mysql_query($strSQL);
            $resp = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
            {
                if ($format == 'full')
                {
                    $resp[$row['permKey']] = array('ID' => $row['ID'], 'Name' => $row['permName'], 'Key' => $row['permKey']);
                } else {
                    $resp[] = $row['ID'];
                }
            }
            return $resp;
        }

        function getRolePerms($role)
        {
            if (is_array($role))
            {
                $roleSQL = "SELECT * FROM `role_perms` WHERE `roleID` IN (" . implode(",",$role) . ") ORDER BY `ID` ASC";
            } else {
                $roleSQL = "SELECT * FROM `role_perms` WHERE `roleID` = " . floatval($role) . " ORDER BY `ID` ASC";
            }
            $data = mysql_query($roleSQL);
            $perms = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
            {
                $pK = strtolower($this->getPermKeyFromID($row['permID']));
                if ($pK == '') { continue; }
                if ($row['value'] === '1') {
                    $hP = true;
                } else {
                    $hP = false;
                }
                $perms[$pK] = array('perm' => $pK,'inheritted' => true,'value' => $hP,'Name' => $this->getPermNameFromID($row['permID']),'ID' => $row['permID']);
            }
            return $perms;
        }

        function getUserPerms($userID)
        {
            $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `user_perms` WHERE `userID` = " . floatval($userID) . " ORDER BY `addDate` ASC";
            $data = mysql_query($strSQL);
            $perms = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
            {
                $pK = strtolower($this->getPermKeyFromID($row['permID']));
                if ($pK == '') { continue; }
                if ($row['value'] == '1') {
                    $hP = true;
                } else {
                    $hP = false;
                }
                $perms[$pK] = array('perm' => $pK,'inheritted' => false,'value' => $hP,'Name' => $this->getPermNameFromID($row['permID']),'ID' => $row['permID']);
            }
            return $perms;
        }

        function userHasRole($roleID)
        {
            foreach($this->userRoles as $k => $v)
            {
                if (floatval($v) === floatval($roleID))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        function hasPermission($permKey)
        {
            $permKey = strtolower($permKey);
            if (array_key_exists($permKey,$this->perms))
            {
                if ($this->perms[$permKey]['value'] === '1' || $this->perms[$permKey]['value'] === true)
                {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        function getUsername($userID)
        {
            $strSQL = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = " . floatval($userID) . " LIMIT 1";
            $data = mysql_query($strSQL);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($data);
            return $row[0];
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: 1. Yes, it would be a great idea. `mysql_` is deprecated. 2. The code is very short. You can quickly go through the function calls one by one and evaluate.

Comment: 1) It's called __construct(); 2) do you have ID as float??

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `$mysqli` property to this class and have the `MySQLi` object passed to it in constructor.

```
class ACL {

  private $mysqli;

  public function __construct(MySQLi $mysqli) {
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    /* rest of your code */
  }
}
```

The rest is pretty much search and replace.

Comment: Could you explain how to get the MySQLi object into the class more?

Answer (score 1):

The code is written to support PHP4. That tells me two things: firstly, the author couldn't use mysqli even if he wanted to, because PHP4 didn't have it, and secondly, the code is probably pretty old, and was written before the PHP devs started really trying to push developers to use mysqli instead of mysql.

If it's well written, then converting it to use mysqli instead should be a piece of cake. The API differences between mysql and mysqli at a basic level are actually pretty minimal. The main difference is the requirement to pass the connection object to the query functions. This was optional in mysql and frequently left out, as it seems to have been in this code.

So your main challenge is getting that connection object variable to be available wherever you make a mysqli function call. The easy way to do that is just to make it a property of the class, so it's available everywhere in the class.

I also recommend you drop the other php4 support bits; they're not needed, and they get in the way.

Comment: Is the floats a php4 support?

Comment: no, the floats are not php4 related. The only possible reason for using floats for IDs would be if you're expecting seriously massive ID values that would overflow an integer. If you're using a 64-bit compiled version of PHP, that's never going to be an issue.

Comment: the bit that is obviously for php4 is `function ACL`, which is commented as such. The developer has also misspelt the php5 equivalent `__construct()`, so there's a bit of work to do there.